# golang parse POST request

Tags: post, go, http-post

I have a HTTP POST request with payload

```
indices=0%2C1%2C2
```

Here is my golang backend code

```
err := r.ParseForm()
if err != nil {
    http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    return
}
log.Println("r.PostForm", r.PostForm)
log.Println("r.Form", r.Form)

body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
if err != nil {
    http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    return
}
log.Println("r.Body", string(body))

values, err := url.ParseQuery(string(body))
if err != nil {
    http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    return
}
log.Println("indices from body", values.Get("indices"))
```

Output:

```
r.PostForm map[]
r.Form map[]
r.Body indices=0%2C1%2C2
indices from body 0,1,2
```

Why is it that the POST request is not parsed by `r.ParseForm()`, while manaully parsing it with `url.ParseQuery(string(body))` gives the correct result?

Comment: are you sending your request with the right content type? it should be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer thanks. that solved the issue. wonder why it was not mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23797348/1472186

Comment: rephrasing as an answer then

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem is not in your server code which is fine, but simply that your client, whatever it is, is missing the correct `Content-Type` header for POST forms. Simply set the header to

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

In your client.

Comment: Same thing when you're working with XML / JSON. If your request is sending json always set the header ``Content-Type: application/json``. Same for XML. Its a very good practice, (and sometimes mandatory), to configure the request according to its content to avoid backends the need to "guess" what's processing.

Answer (score 8):

> Get value form your params use PostFormValue("params") from your http.Request

```
err := r.ParseForm() 
if err != nil{
       panic(err)
}

params := r.PostFormValue("params") // to get params value with key
```